# What is the idiomatic way to refer to a singleton list constructor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, idioms, pointfree

Short form: is there a more idiomatic way to write `(\a->[a])` ?

Long form: For any data type `Foo a`, if I have a function `f :: Foo a -> b` and I need to write something like...

```
wrapAndF a = f $ Foo a
```

...I can make it point-free by writing

```
wrapAndF = f . Foo
```

But if my function `g :: [a] -> b` operates on lists and my wrapper looks like this...

```
wrapAndG a = g [a]
```

...what is the most idiomatic way to write it point-free? I know I can write an explicit lambda:

```
wrapAndG = g . (\x->[x])
```

or, mirroring the use of the constructor in the Foo example, use the list constructor `(:)`, but then I have to flip the arguments:

```
wrapAndG = g . flip (:) []
```

...but what is the idiomatic way to refer to the singleton list constructor function? I expected to find a standard function with signature `a -> [a]`, but I couldn't find it on Hoogle or Data.List.

There is of course the alternative of simply not writing it point-free (and that is certainly a valid answer) but since passing type constructors around as wrapper functions seems really useful, it felt odd that I couldn't find a standard function to wrap a value into a list, so I figured I may be missing something.

Comment: Seems a bit obvious, but what about an operator section - `(:[])`. 5 characters, technically longer than `pure` but it certainly better expresses the intent of 'making a singleton list'.

Comment: Indeed, solutions using `return` or `pure` are interesting because they look beyond the list, but I agree that `(:[])` represents the intent in that particular case better!

Comment: @user2407038 I think I saw that called the "monkey head operator" a few years ago. I'd guess it's fairly idiomatic.

Comment: I does indeed look like a monkey head ! Lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Echoing the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660083/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-refer-to-a-singleton-list-constructor-in-haskell#comment72446217_42660083) by user2407038 and chi, `(:[])` is a fine way of spelling it if you want something specific to lists:

```
wrapAndG = g . (:[])
```

Answer (score 10):

For lists `pure` does what you want:

```
wrapAndG = g . pure
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found the answer, thanks to [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io), which was linked to in another question. A nice, point-free way to write `wrapAndG` is

```
wrapAndG = g . return
```

This uses the fact that lists are instances of `Monad`.